# Best practice to avoid naming collisions - lwc app

Tags: bestpractice, namespace, unlocked-package, prefix

I wonder what is known best practice to deal with name collisions for salesforce lwc applications. Do we need to prefix names of classes, components, etc. with abbreviations. Unlocked package with namespace is the best solution when an application is not distributed via AppExchange?

To clarify my question - having access to Salesforce DX development model with deployments to production org is it a better idea to create unlocked package with namespace or use sfdx force:source:deploy with prefixed classes, components etc.?

Is it actual for SFDX deployment model: [Trailhead Naming conventions](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/success-cloud-coding-conventions/choose-naming-conventions-sc)?

Comment: Name collisions for what? Your own packages? Metadata in production? What's your end goal?

Comment: This question seems broad and opinion based, making it a poor fit for this site.

Comment: Name collisions between metadata in producton ie. an app that in fact is not managed package.

Comment: I asked because creation a prefix for lwc component might be problematic indeed. eg. "prefix_MyComponent" - possible only when starting with lower case and kebab case looks like "prefix_-my-component".